# The weird length of varchar and nvarchar in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, varchar, nvarchar

I had a question about the Transcat SQL, below is the sql code;

```
DECLARE @main nVARCHAR(max);

--there are over 4000 characters to @main 
set @main = '01234567890123456789...';
Print len(@main)
```

the length of @main is correct, e.g. 4007
however, if I change the code to below:

```
DECLARE @main nVARCHAR(max);

--there are over 4000 characters to @main 
set @main = N'01234567890123456789...';
Print len(@main)
```

the length of @main will always be 4000, it is weird, I don't understand.
Another thing is if I change the code to below:

```
DECLARE @main nVARCHAR(max), @split nVARCHAR(500);

--there are 500 characters to @split 
set @split = '01234567890123456789...';
set @main = @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split;
Print len(@main)
```

The length of @main is 4000, why? No matter I add letter N before '01234567890123456789...'?
if I change the @split to varchar(500)
    DECLARE @main nVARCHAR(max), @split VARCHAR(500);

```
--there are 500 characters to @split 
set @split = '01234567890123456789...';
-- 10 @split
set @main = @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split;
Print len(@main)
```

The length of @main is correct, no matter I add letter N before ''01234567890123456789...' or not, the length of @main is always 5000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into issues with implicit types of string expressions. With the exception of `MAX` lengths, a `VARCHAR` type can hold 8000 chars (limited by the size of a page in SQL SERVER) and, because `NVARCHAR` stores double-byte chars, it can hold half the number of chars (4000). By default string expressions (literals, concatenated strings etc) are evaluated using either a max length of 8000 for `varchar` or a max len of `4000` for `nvarchar`. You have to explicitly cast the expression to a `MAX` type to get the behavior you expect.

In your first example, your string expression `'01234567890123456789...'` is implicitly evaluated as a `VARCHAR(8000)` which is then implicitly converted to `NVARCHAR(MAX)` so it correctly retains the number of characters since your expression only had 4007 chars.

When you convert your string expression to unicode (i.e. `N'01234567890123456789...'` it evaluates the string as `NVARCHAR(4000)` before assigning the value to your `NVARCHAR(MAX)` variable.

Change your second example to this:

```
DECLARE @main nVARCHAR(max);

--there are over 4000 characters to @main 
set @main = CAST(N'01234567890123456789...' AS NVARCHAR(MAX));
Print len(@main)
```

And it will behave as you expect.

Likewise when you're concatenating the `@split` variables, SQL Server is evaluating the expression as `NVARCHAR(4000)` you have to cast the leftmost value as `NVARCHAR(MAX)` in order to have the expression evaluated as `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

```
DECLARE @main nVARCHAR(max), @split nVARCHAR(500);

--there are 500 characters to @split 
set @split = '01234567890123456789...';
set @main = CAST(@split as NVARCHAR(MAX)) + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split + @split;
Print len(@main)
```

It will work.

Comment: I have tested your modified sql script, the result is the same with my original examples.

Comment: I just ran my first example with a 10,000 char string, worked as expected. I ran my second example with @split being a 500 char string and it worked as expected.