# cannot store 5000 chars in NVARCHAR and VARCHAR

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, varchar, nvarchar

I have to create a dynamic sql query in SP. the dynamic query is 5000 chars, and I used NVARCHAR(MAX),VARCHAR(MAX), NVARCHAR(6000), VARCHAR(6000) but they all truncate to 4000 chars

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(8000)
set @SCRIPT =' ASDADASD ASDA  DSADAD AD AS D......' +@VAR1+ ' AWDAWd'    -- 6000 CHARS
PRINT LEN(@SCRIPT)      -- THIS PRINTS "4000"
PRINT @SCRIPT           -- THIS PRINTS ONLY 4000 CHARS
```

How can increase the size of STRING? I have read many post but I couldnt get it done. Please help me?

Comment: I suspect the key bit that's mssing from your question is that it's not a pure 6000 character *literal*, but instead you've building it up from multiple *separate* literals and falling foul of [truncation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.ilgenerator(v=vs.110).aspx): "If the result of the concatenation of strings exceeds the limit of 8,000 bytes, the result is truncated. However, if at least one of the strings concatenated is a large value type, truncation does not occur."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `nvarchar(max)` data type instead.
Be sure to prefix string literals with the N designator (`N' ASDADASD...'`). Cast explicitely so the default limitation will not apply:

```
set @script=convert(nvarchar(max),N'very-long-literal')
```

(reference: [The weird length of varchar and nvarchar in T-SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8115972/the-weird-length-of-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-t-sql?rq=1))

EDIT: full working example:

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT nvarchar(max)
SET @SCRIPT=convert(nvarchar(max),N' ASDADASD ASDA  DSADAD AD AS D......')+replicate(convert(nvarchar(max),N'A'),6000)
PRINT LEN(@SCRIPT) -- this prints "6036"
PRINT @SCRIPT -- this prints all 6036 chars of the string
```

Comment: @ayilmaz I updated my answer with a full working code sample. which version of SQL server are you using? my successful test was done on a 10.50.1617.

Comment: but in replicate function, what should I give instead of 'A'

Comment: that `replicate` is just a filler for the example. just use your actual full-length script string and omit the `replicate` part.

Comment: your example works but mine doesnt. I forgot to mention that there are variables CONCATed in the middle of the NVARCHAR. Can that cause problem? I edited my code above

Comment: cast the concatenated parts as well: `... +convert(nvarchar(max),@VAR1)+ ...` (and, as a side note, ensure that such @VAR1 arguments contain only escaped literals or no user-generated data at all, to prevent SQL injection attack vulnerability)

Answer (score 1):

NVARCHAR(n) is limited to 4000, VARCHAR + NVARCHAR = NVARCHAR. Look at

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT VARCHAR(8000)
set @SCRIPT = replicate('A',6000)+'A'
select len(@SCRIPT) 

set @SCRIPT = replicate('A',6000)+N'A'
select len(@SCRIPT), 'mind NVARCHAR'
```

Cast everything NVARCHAR(MAX) to be sure.

```
DECLARE @SCRIPT NVARCHAR(MAX) =replicate('A',7000)
set @SCRIPT = @SCRIPT +'A'
select len(@SCRIPT) 

set @SCRIPT = @SCRIPT + cast(replicate('A',6000) as NVARCHAR(MAX))
select len(@SCRIPT)
```

Comment: Hi, first one looks like working but when I set my script to @SCRIPT. It again truncates to 4000

Comment: your example works but mine doesnt. I forgot to mention that there are variables CONCATed in the middle of the NVARCHAR. Can that cause problem? I edited my code above

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN

> Variable-length, non-Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 8,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for varchar are char varying or character varying.

So just specify a size of (max)